# Python - how many times does a word appear in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I got the string  `a = "bob"` and `b = "bobob"`

when I perform `a in b`, how can I count that `bob` appears twice in `b`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generator expression that iterates through a rolling window of `b` over the difference in lengths between `a` and `b` and tests if the slice of `b` in that window is equal to `a`:

```
sum(b[i: i + len(a)] == a for i in range(len(b) - len(a) + 1))
```

This returns: `2`